# extracting specific website url from string

Tags: javascript, regex

H have a regular expression that matches website urls

```
.+\.\w\w.*(.*)
```

I would like to extract the url that matches my string for example:

> what is google.com?

when i run my code

```
var x = /.+\.\w\w.*(.*)/
x.exec( "what is <http://google.com>?" )
```

it instead returns

> ["what is http://google.com?", ""]

instead of just returning the url that i want it to match, why is this happening?

Comment: Use a regexp testing site such as regex101 to test your expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Description

In your expression the `.` is grabbing any character and the `+` or `*` makes the capture greedy. The net effect is that all characters are captured.

```regex
([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6})\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- Finds strings that resemble urls
- ignores any leading `http` or `https`
- splits the query substring from the URL

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/kB1mS6/3

**Sample text**

```
what is <http://google.com>?
what is www.ibm.com?
are these the Droids.I.com?Lookingfor=Yes
```

**Sample Matches**

- Capture group 0 gets the url and query string if it exists
- capture group 1 gets the url
- Capture group 2 gets the query string if it exists

```
MATCH 1
1.  [16-26] `google.com`
2.  [26-26] ``

MATCH 2
1.  [37-48] `www.ibm.com`
2.  [48-49] `?`

MATCH 3
1.  [64-76] `Droids.I.com`
2.  [76-91] `?Lookingfor=Yes`
```

---

## To further capture additional words in the sentence you can modify the expression:

```
([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6})\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]*)(?:>?\s+(down))?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

## Examples

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/kB1mS6/4

**Sample Text**

```
what is <http://google.com> down?
what is www.ibm.com?
are these the Droids.I.com?Lookingfor=Yes
why is http://www.bing.com down?
why is www.bing.com down?
```

**Sample Matches**

```
MATCH 1
1.  `google.com`
2.  ``
3.  `down`

MATCH 2
1.  `www.ibm.com`
2.  `?`

MATCH 3
1.  `Droids.I.com`
2.  `?Lookingfor=Yes`

MATCH 4
1.  `www.bing.com`
2.  ``
3.  `down`

MATCH 5
1.  `www.bing.com`
2.  ``
3.  `down`
```

This slightly modifies the expression from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3809435/3836229 to separately capture the URL.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your regex does not really match URLs, but in fact a lot more.

For some inspiration on how to match URLs, you could have a look at the proposal from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3809435/3836229):

```
https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)
```

Comment: ah so thats why, i tested out your regex and it works out perfectly when i try exec command. i have one more question though, i have an existing regex that is using my old similar pattern to match a sentence. /(is\s*(.+\.\w\w.*)\sdown?)/ how do I integrate my old url regex pattern to yours?

Comment: I tried /(is\s*([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*))\sdown[?])/